# ZEND: FlashMessenger and redirect() method is not working in live site

Tags: zend-framework

I need some help with ZEND FlashMessenger and redirect method. These are working absolutely fine on my test server but not in live server.

Getting an warning  "**Warning: Missing argument 1 for Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::direct() in /home/******/public_html/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/FlashMessenger.php on line 309**" . Actually, i am storing error and success message using this after completion of a action and displaying the error/success message on another page after redirection.

Also i am using "**$this->_redirect($url);**" to redirect to another action url (by using $url; $url='http://www.abcd.com'). This is also working on my test site but not working on live site. I have used this on my other live site as well and found no issue with them.

Your suggestion/help will be much appreciated for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show me the code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the code, Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::direct() is not used for redirect, but for adding a message, see below:

```
/**
 * Strategy pattern: proxy to addMessage()
 *
 * @param  string $message
 * @return void
 */
public function direct($message)
{
    return $this->addMessage($message);
}
```

Also, what did you mean by "not working" on live. What does it do or what's the error?

Comment: Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::direct() is displaying the above warning. and $this->_redirect($url) is generating 'Page not found' error. Also, please mention where(in which file) shall i add the above code.

Comment: 1. As I told you, you should use Zend_Controller_Action::_redirect() and not Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger::direct(); 2. If it redirects you to 404, then you probably have to debug your routing/mod_rewrite/verify that this url/page really exists; 3. I don't know your project structure to tell you exact place for _redirect() call. Perhaps, it should be in the place where you currently have it. But again, if you're getting 404, see the url in your browser and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone else runs across this -

I ran into the same warning, and was baffled because I was not calling the direct() anywhere. I finally figured out that it was related to the way I was accessing the FlashMessenger to add a message.

Not sure if this is the same issues that this user encountered, since no code is posted, but for me this code was what was causing the error:

```
$this->_helper->FlashMessenger()->addMessage('Success!');
```

I found that using this method made the warning disappear:

```
$this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Success!');
```